# PHP 5.2.17 datetime difference

Tags: php, datetime

First before anyone writes it, I know there are many topics about it already and I have checked a lot of them somehow nothing works for me.

I have in mysql 2 datetime fields (date_in, date_out) I just need to subtract date in from  date_out which is easy in php 5.3 but I am on someones server and cant update it... date in the both fields is formated like this (2014-06-02 16:43:47)

Example below works fine as it is (i found it somewhere on the Stack)

```
$start = new DateTime('2010-10-12');
$end = new DateTime();
$days = round(($end->format('U') - $start->format('U')) / (60*60*24));
```

BUT when I change $start and $end to my data from DB, last line $days throws out an error (the -> format('U')) seems to be a problem. How can this be fixed?

(difference between end/start will never be greater than hour at most)

Comment: Try using Carbon for such stuff: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-difference

Comment: @JohnConde *cough* 5.2.17 *cough*

Comment: @DaveRandom I tried John's paste with 5.2.17 on codeviper, same result being 1346, if that's the desired end-result. http://codepad.viper-7.com/TLLKyk

Comment: @DaveRandom I don't think there was anything in that code that was not available in 5.2. I suspect their DB values are the issue.

Comment: Post the values you are getting from the database

Comment: Well with this specific issue, `strtotime()`/`time()` should be all that's required anyway - and would actually be microscopically more efficient (`DateTime::format()` returns a string)

Comment: This is what is inserted to DB
    $date_in = new DateTime();
    $date_in = $date_in->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
it spits out this 2014-06-02 16:43:47

Comment: [Still works for me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sDsbBp). Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnConde I don't see/hear any more "coughs" ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- The miracle of modern medicine! :)

Comment: @JohnConde You literally wrote was I was thinking lol!

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out finally!

```
$date_inA = $sql_array[3];
$date_inB = new DateTime($date_inA);
$date_outA = $sql_array[4];
$date_outB = new DateTime($date_outA);

$diff = round(($date_outB->format('U') - $date_inB->format('U')) / (60*60*24));
```

I needed to change string object value to datetime object, I thought it was already date time object in DB...

Comment: Great. +1 glad to hear it. Cheers